# Matlab - create a line mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a mask of size mxn.

I would like to add a line to this mask, such that all the points which passes through it will be set to true.

The line is defined by two points: (x1,y1),(x2,y2).

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Please notice that I only have the Image processing toolbox.

Example for possible input, and desired output:

```
%generates a mask
m = 152; n=131; 
mask = false(m,n);
%example for possible input points
y1 = 68; x1 = 69;
y2 = 28; x2 = 75;

% code for adding the line into the mask%

imshow(mask);
```

desired result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a line or line segment?

Comment: @Suever - what is the difference between the two?

Comment: In one case you want only the things between the two points and the other you want anything along the infinite line that goes through those two points.

Comment: @Suever, I see. I need a line segment in my case (only pixels between the points). I added an example. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think that your example coordinates don't quite match your example image. It looks like in your image `x1-x2 == 1`

Comment: @Suever - thanks! I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first determine how many pixels there are between the two points by computing the distance (in pixels) between the points. We can then use `linspace` to create a linear spacing of points between the two end points specifying this number of points. We can then round the result to get pixel coordinates.

Then we can use `sub2ind` to set these values within the mask to `1`.

```
% Distance (in pixels) between the two endpoints
nPoints = ceil(sqrt((x2 - x1).^2 + (y2 - y1).^2)) + 1;

% Determine x and y locations along the line
xvalues = round(linspace(x1, x2, nPoints));
yvalues = round(linspace(y1, y2, nPoints));

% Replace the relevant values within the mask
mask(sub2ind(size(mask), yvalues, xvalues)) = 1;
```

[image]